# Which of these are homotopy equivalent? $S^1, \mathbb{R}, \{*\}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Which of these spaces are homotopy equivalent: $S^1, \mathbb{R}, \{*\}$?

I found a homotopy equivalence between $\mathbb{R}$ and the one point space $\{*\}$, so they are homotopy equivalent.

The sphere and $\mathbb{R}$ are not homotopy-equivalent because the $\pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ whereas $\pi_1(\mathbb{R})$ is trivial (since we just proved that $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible). Is there a nicer way of seeing this without using the fundamental group?

Is $S^n$ for $n>1$ homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $S^n$ is not homotopy equivalent to a point.

Comment: Ok, can u explain why? $S^n$ is simply connected right?

Comment: $S^n$ is simply connected if $n \geq 2$, but $\pi_n(S^n) = \mathbb{Z}$, whereas $\pi_k(\text{pt}) = 0$ for all $k \geq 1$.

Comment: I don't yet know what $\pi_n$ is for $n>1$. Can u pls explain it without the use of this?

Comment: You only need to know what $\pi_1(\cdot)$ is (and that it's a topological invariant).

Comment: This is not true, $S^n$ is not homotopy equivalent to a point. In fact, its n-th homology group or likewise its n-th homotopy group are nonzero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked several questions at once:

> Which of these spaces are homotopy equivalent: $S^1, \mathbb{R}, \{*\}$?

You've pretty much figured out the answer to this question already.  You know $\mathbb{R}$ and the one-point space *are* homotopy equivalent, and $S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are *not* homotopy equivalent.  Homotopy equivalence is an equivalence relation, so you don't need to check if $S^1$ is homotopy equivalent to the one-point space.  You know that it's not, because otherwise $S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}$ would be homotopy equivalent by transitivity.

> Is there a nicer way of seeing this without using the fundamental group?

This is pretty much why fundamental groups and other homotopy invariants exist; in order to distinguish spaces.

> Is $S^n$ for $n>1$ homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$?

No, but I'm not sure how to answer this question without going further into algebraic topology.  As I alluded in the comments, there are higher homotopy groups $\pi_k(X)$ which are also homotopy invariants.  It can be shown $\pi_k(S^n) = 0$ if $1 \leq k < n$, and $\pi_n(S^n) = \mathbb{Z}$.  Also, $\pi_k(X) = 0$ for all $k \geq 1$ if $X$ is contractible.  So this tells you $S^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are not homotopy equivalent.

Comment: That clears it up, thanks